# What's the difference between DIAMETER and 802.1X Authentication?

Tags: authentication, radius, ieee-802.1x, aaa

I'm studying the 802.1.X authentication guidelines and the DIAMETER protcol as successor of RADIUS but i can't figure out what are the main difference between pure 802.1X Port-Based Authentication and DIAMETER.
What are their differences?

Comment: 802.1X communicates with a server to determine authentication. DIAMETER is simply an alternative to RADIUS. You cannot compare 802.1X to a server, but you could compare RADIUS and DIAMETER.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

802.1X provides client-side/front-end port-level authentication (between suplicant and authenticator). RADIUS and Diameter provide back-end authentication (between authenticator and authentication server).

Essentially, they are different things. 802.1X is an application while RADIUS/Diameter can potentially provide authentication for various applications.

Note that *Diameter* is no acronym like *RADIUS*, but a play of words - the diameter is twice the radius.

Comment: ahahah didn't notice the joke, that's nice